# How to detect a full mouse click (both down and up) on a control?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mouseevent

In WPF with MVVM (and no code-behind), say I have a `Rectangle`. If the user clicks on the rectangle, I want to perform an action. I effectively want the action to occur on mouse up. **However**, I only want the action triggered if they performed a **full click** (i.e. both mouse down and mouse up) on the rectangle. If they clicked down over some other control, held the mouse down, moved it over the rectangle, and released the mouse, I do **not** want to trigger the action.

There is the `MouseDown` event and the `MouseUp` event, but what I effectively want is a "`MouseClick`" event (like in WinForms). Is there any built-in mouse click event/trigger/something functionality? If not, what would be the best way to approach this? Custom trigger? Attached behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it isn't perfect, but I created a custom trigger to solve the problem. I'm still open to any better solutions if anyone has one.

```
public class MouseClickTrigger : TriggerBase<UIElement>
{
    private bool _isMouseDown;

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        this.AssociatedObject.MouseDown += this.AssociatedObject_MouseDown;
        this.AssociatedObject.MouseUp += this.AssociatedObject_MouseUp;
        this.AssociatedObject.MouseLeave += this.AssociatedObject_MouseLeave;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        this.AssociatedObject.MouseDown -= this.AssociatedObject_MouseDown;
        this.AssociatedObject.MouseUp -= this.AssociatedObject_MouseUp;
        this.AssociatedObject.MouseLeave -= this.AssociatedObject_MouseLeave;
    }

    private void AssociatedObject_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        this._isMouseDown = true;
    }

    private void AssociatedObject_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        bool fullClick = this._isMouseDown;
        this._isMouseDown = false;
        if (fullClick)
        {
            this.InvokeActions(e);
        }
    }

    private void AssociatedObject_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this._isMouseDown = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Whaaaaat??? I dont your problem... Why cant you do something like this:

private bool isMouseDownInRect = false;

```
    <Rectangle Width="100" Height="100" MouseUp="UIElement_OnMouseUp" MouseDown="UIElement_OnMouseDown" Fill="Black"></Rectangle>

    private void UIElement_OnMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isMouseDownInRect)
        {
          // My code  
        }

        isMouseDownInRect = false;
    }

    private void UIElement_OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        isMouseDownInRect = true;
    }
```

I hope this is what you asking for.

EDIT:

Dont forget to handle the mouse_enter/leave event...

Comment: This will fail, if a user press' mousedown, holds pressed, moves away, releases the button. Now the flag is set to true and user can click anywhere and onMouseUp will be executed and code in the if block will get executed.

Comment: then add mouse_leave event and there you go... but the idea stays the same which is to use a flag...